# Convert Image to File in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i convert `Image` object to `File` object or `Stream<List<int>>` in Flutter? I can't get image path, because i load it via URL.

Flutter: 1.12.13+hotfix.5

Comment: Does this work? [File.fromUri](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/File.fromUri.html)

Comment: yes. it does. Thank your for the hint